# Fading Between Div's with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<section>

<div id="first">
---content
</div>

<div id="second">
---content
</div>

</section>
```

Upon page load, the second div and it's contents are invisible (I don't know if it's better to use .hide() or CSS).  I would like to, using Jquery, upon some interaction on the page, make the first div fade out and be replaced with the second div.

On my own so far I've used fadein() and fadeout(), however it makes the divs jump around on the page.  I'm trying to seamlessly fade out the contents of div 1 and replace with div 2, consuming the exact space as div 1 and without making the formatting of the page jump around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(document).ready();` as listener.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").fadeOut();
    $("#second").fadeIn();
});
```

Use fadeIn(), fadeOut() to have a simple effect.

Plain javascript

```
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
    second = document.getElementById('second');

window.onload = function() {
   first.style.display = 'none';
   second.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Update:**

Use `position: relative on section` and put `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` on child, in your case. (#first, #second)

```
#first, #second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear in OP, but when trying that it makes the content below move around during the transition.  The first div fades out, content below jumps up then back down as div 2 starts fading in.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out, that was very close but the second element fades right to the top of the window, is it possible to make it fill the section instead?

Comment: So far that's perfect, thanks :D  I thought complex javascript might be needed, turns out just some nifty positioning!

Comment: Glad I've helped. Once, you master the position relative absolute relationship. It can take your layout to the next level.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do with toggle class. [I don't recommend doing fadeIn and fadeOut.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88#issuecomment-72400007)

**CSS**

```
    #first {
        background-color: red;
        height: 250px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
           -moz-transition: .25s all ease;
            -ms-transition: .25s all ease;
             -o-transition: .25s all ease;
                transition: .25s all ease;
    } 

    #second {
        background-color: green;
        height: 250px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
           -moz-transition: .25s all ease;
            -ms-transition: .25s all ease;
             -o-transition: .25s all ease;
                transition: .25s all ease;
    }

    .hidden {
        height: 0 !important;
        opacity: 0 !important;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <section id="parent">
        <div id="first">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus sequi iure, nesciunt laudantium a beatae autem, commodi culpa, quasi vitae sint ad. Itaque repellat cum voluptate, est aut provident ipsum?
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="hidden">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus sequi iure, nesciunt laudantium a beatae autem, commodi culpa, quasi vitae sint ad. Itaque repellat cum voluptate, est aut provident ipsum?
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(function(){
        $('#first, #second').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/bngnxty9/

I have added click on body event, you could replace your own event there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.fadeOut()` to fade `#first` out, and to get `#second` to show at the same exact time that `#first` disappears, use the callback in `$.fadeOut()`

```js
$("button").on('click',function() {
  $('#first').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#second').removeClass('hidden');
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  first</div>

<div id="second" class="hidden">
  second</div>

<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think right now to seamlessly fade between both divs (overlapping each one) is to have both overlapped using absolute positioning, the issue is that sending both to absolute position doesn't allow us to expand containers (so JavaScript/jQuery would be required to handle that).

So, you need something like:

```
  section {
    position: relative;
  }
  #first, #second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

When you do the fadeOut/fadeIn thing, the divs will make the fade in/out overlapping each other, not stacking, however, you need to give a height to the `<section >` element, which can be the same of the tallest element between **#first** and **#second**, or you can also set that after the fade switching has been completed.

Hope this helps